# How to test a function that returns an arrow function with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a function like this:

```js
export const myFunc = (a, b ,callBack) => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        callBack(a+b);
    }, 10);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
};
```

I'm able to test the callback function just fine by doing this:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('myFunc', () => {
    const callBack = jest.fn();

    it('runs myFunc', () => {
        myFunc(1, 2, callBack);
        jest.runAllTimers();

        expect(callBack).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
    });
```

However, the last line `return () => clearTimeout(timer)` is never tested somehow. Jest report just says this line `function not covered` and `statement not covered`. Can anyone please tell me a way to cover this line without using any other external testing library like enzyme?

Comment: Enzyme isn't suitable because the code doesn't contain React components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function isn't called, so it's not covered.

Another test would be:

```
    let cleanup = myFunc(1, 2, callBack);
    cleanup()
    jest.runAllTimers();
    expect(callBack).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Just one more follow-up, how come the callBack is not called here?

Comment: It's not called because it's called after a timeout, which is cancelled by clearTimeout - that's the purpose of `cleanup` function